# Change order by in mysql for joda-time durations like PT1000S

Tags: mysql, grails, sql-order-by, jodatime

I am using the joda-time grails plugin in my grails app to deal with durations. The plugin saves durations decoded in milliseconds in the database, prefixes it with "PT" and suffixes with "s". Example `1 minute = PT3600S`

Now I want to order this row. As it is a varchar ordering gets complicated or better not as I want it to be ordered :(

result

```
PT12551S
PT21142S
PT23240S
PT4672S
PT4792S
PT4877S
```

expected (if it type is int...)

```
PT4672S
PT4792S
PT4877S
PT12551S
PT21142S
PT23240S
```

Any idea how to work around this? Can I change the format of the data that is stored in db? Can I change the ordering to regard the length of the entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the best way to do it is not to use this kind of shortcut for now. I am now saving the durations as integers. That way it is easy to order and add.